# Inserting a file into the project - trying to eliminate OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, openfiledialog

I have a file (.doc file), that is required for the software to work properly. The program starts with the user opening the file manually (OpenFileDialog) and continuing on normally. Is there a way to have the file already within the project so the user doesn't have to manually open the file each time the project runs? Thanks!

Here's a link to the tutorial I used to make this project. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYse5nh5nB8

Comment: Add it to `Resources`

Comment: @ArtemKulikov   That's what I thought as well, but I wanted to ask and make sure. My next question is, how can I call a file from the resources to be used? Is there a variable name I can give it? [VariableName=Properties.Resources.File] ?

Comment: global::Tests.Properties.Resources.FileX;
which in here `Tests` is project name, and `FileX` is resource file name

Comment: Add a field in appconfig named documentname. and before opens file dialog check if is empty. If not then openfiledoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can Add your document with right click context menu Add->Existing Item, in your project.
2. Select Properties of document by right clicking and Change Build Action from Compile to Embedded Resource and Copy to Output Directory" of the report file to "Copy always".

You can get the path of this file as

```
string fileName = "YourDocument.doc";
string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, fileName);
```

once you have file path you can read its contents.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Please forgive my ignorance, I'm still learning, but I'm getting a red line under "LocalConstants". I do however have "LocalDataStoreSlot", "LocalizableAttribute", and "LocalVariableInfo" as options when I start to type "Local". Any suggestions for this? Thanks again!!

Comment: @Kayla You need not to add the Local constants, It was added by mistake, here the goal is to get the path of the file which you need to read, So only folder path and filename are sufficient.Have removed that part from code.

Comment: It works! I had a problem at first. The `fileName` from the `string path` line was always in red. I fixed the problem by simply replacing `fileName` with `"YourDocument.doc"`. The new line looks like this: `string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "YourDocument.doc");` Thanks again!! :)

Comment: Cheers!! and I think redline  problem can be solved by replacing string fileName = "YourDocument.doc"; with string fileName = @"YourDocument.doc"; i.e just adding @ sign before value. I have not tried though.